# MVC.net, with a form in partiaview, return validations and after post to Parent View

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, return-value, partial-views

I make a sendemail form in a partialview to used in differents views, for example( contacts, inscriptions)

whell my problem is I can't return the errors message or success message to the parent view

I try differents ways, my two better times are:

-) in the control use Partialviewresult(showing the messages but in the screen is only the partial view, make a redirect)

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult _SendMail(MailModel obj)
    {

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(obj.from));
            mail.To.Add(obj.to);
            mail.From = new MailAddress(obj.from);
            mail.Subject = obj.Subject;
            string Body = obj.Body;
            mail.Body = Body;
            mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SendMailerController.sendMailer(mail);
            ViewBag.courriel = "- votre courriel à été envoyé";
            return PartialView();
        }
        else
        {
            ViewBag.courriel = "- votre courriel à été envoyé";
            return PartialView();
        }
    }
```

send the name the parent view to partialview to hide imput and in the controler use action result with redirectToAaction... showing the good View but don't the messages.

parent controller

```
 public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }
```

parent view CONTACT.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Contact";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

        <section id="emailForm">
            @Html.Partial("_SendMail", new ViewDataDictionary(ViewData) { { "adresse", "Contact" } })
        </section>
```

partial view _SendMail

```
@model IdentitySample.Models.MailModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Evoyez-nous un Courriel";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<fieldset>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("_SendMail", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new
    {
        @class = "form-horizontal",
        role = "form",
        @id = "Formulaire"
    }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-error" })
    <div class="text-success"> @ViewBag.courriel </div>
    <table class="col-md-4">
        <tr>
            <td>To:</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.to)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Suject:</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Message</td>
            <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body)</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="hidden" name="adresse" value="@ViewData["adresse"]" />
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.from)
            </td>
            <td><input type="submit" value="Send" class="btn btn-default" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
        <br/>

    }
</fieldset>
@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

controler send email

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult _SendMail(MailModel obj)
        {

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {

                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(obj.from));
                mail.To.Add(obj.to);
                mail.From = new MailAddress(obj.from);
                mail.Subject = obj.Subject;
                string Body = obj.Body;
                mail.Body = Body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                SendMailerController.sendMailer(mail);
                ViewBag.courriel = "- votre courriel à été envoyé";
                return RedirectToAction(obj.adresse, "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.courriel = "- votre courriel à été envoyé";
                return RedirectToAction("Contact", "Home");
            }
        }
```

and the emai model

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Net.Mail;
namespace IdentitySample.Models
{
    public class MailModel
    {
        public string from { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Courriel")]
        public string to { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(150, ErrorMessage = "Sujet trop long, max. 150 charactéres")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Sujet")]
        public string Subject { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3000, ErrorMessage = "le message est de max. 3000 charactéres")]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        [Display(Name = "Sujet")]
        public string Body { get; set; }

        public string adresse { get; set; }

    }
}
```

PD: the send email service works fine, show the errors or success message is my problem

Comment: If you want a success message when redirecting, you can use TempData to store then message and then retrieve it in the next action and then assign it to ViewBag, but I am unsure why you are redirecting when `ModelState` is invalid (as opposed to returning the view)

Comment: whel I try to return the view.  View Contacts, contient partialView send mail inside the partial view is the form for sending the email, but how is possible return to view Contacts, with the success or error message the sendindprocess?, but if I use the partialview in another view, it's need return to the correct place

Answer (score 0):

finally I made with [AjaxForm](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#ajaxForm) is more easy.

downlload the jquery Plugin.

I made a little change in  my partial view and the signature of the function.

PartialView ready

```
@model IdentitySample.Models.MailModel


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Evoyez-nous un Courriel";
}
<h3>@ViewBag.Title</h3>

<form method="post" class="form-horizontal" role="form" id="sendMail">
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger", @id="validation" })
    <div class="text-success" id="success"> @ViewBag.courriel </div>
    <div class="input-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.to, new { @class = "input-group-addon" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.to, new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder = "votrenom@courriel.com" })
    </div>
    <div class="input-group row">
        <p class="input-group-addon">sujet &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</p>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Subject, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
    <div class="input-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Body, new { @class = "input-group-addon" })
        @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Body, new { @class = "form-control", @rows = "8" })
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" name="adresse" value="@ViewData["adresse"]" />
    <input type="submit" value="Envoyer" class="btn btn-success" />
</form>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/form")
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#sendMail").ajaxForm({
                url: "/Home/_SendMail?obj",
                dataType: 'json',
                success: processJson
            });

            function processJson(data) { 
                // 'data' is the json object returned from the server 
                $("#validation").html("");
                $("#success").html(data);
            }
        });
    </script>
```

function in controler

```
[HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public JsonResult _SendMail(MailModel obj)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
                mail.ReplyToList.Add(new MailAddress(obj.to));
                mail.To.Add(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"]);
                mail.From = new MailAddress(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["mailAccount"]);
                mail.To.Add(new MailAddress(obj.to));
                mail.Subject = "site web - " + obj.Subject;
                string Body = "Courriel de " + obj.to + " Contenu:  " + obj.Body;
                mail.Body = Body;
                mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
                if (!SendMailerController.sendMailer(mail)) return Json("error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
                ViewBag.courriel = "- votre courriel à été envoyé";
                return Json("success", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);  
            }
            return Json("error", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 

        }
```